# Function overloading with default arguments

Tags: typescript, overloading

I have an overloaded function which looks like:

```
function getUserId(request: ContextParameters, requireAuth: true): string;
function getUserId(request: ContextParameters, requireAuth: false): string | undefined;
function getUserId(request: ContextParameters, requireAuth = true): string | undefined {
  const authHeader = request.request.headers.authorization;
  if (authHeader) {
    const token = authHeader.replace('Bearer ', '');
    const payload = jwt.verify(token, 'THISISTHENODESECRET') as TokenPayload;
    return payload.userId;
  }

  if (requireAuth)
    throw new Error('Authentication required');
}

export default getUserId;
```

It takes 2 arguments, one of which has a default argument. So I should only be required to provide 1 argument. However when I try to use this function as follows:

```
const userId = getUserId(request);
```

I get the following error:

```
Expected 2 arguments, but got 1.
```

Is this something expected? or a bug? and how would I go about fixing this?

Also, I realize I can just disable `strictNullChecks` and have no need for overloading but I'd like to keep this on.

Answer (score 0):

Split your overloads:

1. One should not accept `requireAuth` at all.
2. One should be assigning the default value.

Consider this example:

```
function foo(flag: true): true;
function foo(flag: false): false;
function foo(): false
function foo(flag = false): boolean {
    if (flag) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Usage:

```
foo(true)  // true
foo(false) // false
foo()      // false
```

The generated JavaScript is exactly what you would expect:

```
"use strict";
function foo(flag = false) {
    if (flag) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```